# INDEX or FULLTEXT to store a VARCHAR(1000) in MySql

Tags: mysql, indexing, varchar, full-text-indexing

**My purpose**:
 
I need to make `SELECT WHERE string IN ('...')` queries, and `string` is a `VARCHAR (1000)`

**The question:**
I do not know if I should use a *FULLTEXT* index for it or just a simple *INDEX*

**The problem:**
The search will be done making a multiple `UNION` in the query with two similar tables, which contain both the `string` field, so I don't neither know if the *FULLTEXT* will make this faster or not.
*(My idea of FULLTEXT indexes is using them with MATCH AGINST queries)*

**The structure:**
You can see how I structured my multiple `string` fields in the different tables in a question I did before at [How to structure this DATABASE idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177338/how-to-structure-this-database-idea-to-make-it-the-fastest-and-cleanest-as-possi)

**Note:**
This question is about which type of INDEX is better for the case. I just linked the structuring question to give readers more references on what I am doing. It is not a duplicated.

Comment: Do you really need to index a varchar 1,000? – What are you trying to do here?  Your link doesn’t describe what you’re trying to achieve and the type of data you’ll be searching for and upon.

Comment: @Steve It will be a collection of words and phrases. The average lenght won't be more than 400 chars but the 1000 is the length limit. In the link I put an example of query, which checks which from a set of words combination exists in the table. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1-N**

If you’re words and phrases are common and will be duplicated between many rows, you should consider separating them out into a 1-n relationship. That way searching and querying the data could be more efficient by joining them with your data. This may not meet your requirements – it totally depends on the type of words and phrases.

**FULLTEXT**

Indexing a varchar 1000 is a bad idea (I don’t like to make assumptions but this is generally always bad).  Not only will this use a HUGE amount of memory and index space if your dataset grows it will be a hard performance bottle neck to fix when it starts to become an issue.  This is the very reason [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is there, if you’re using MySQL 5.6 or greater you can now use [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) on INNODB tables too – if you’re using an older version it will unfortunately only be supported in MyISAM and that storage engine has is downsides (some rather large ones so please research that before opting for it).

**Proper search**

The best solution would be to use a proper search engine such as [Lucene](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=lucene&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://lucene.apache.org/core/&ei=j1UyUY7TNrCo0AXh2YH4Bg&usg=AFQjCNFUWH4QNE3qjb53P9oILG1p3LwpdQ&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k), [Sphinx](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sphinx%20&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http://sphinxsearch.com/&ei=n1UyUeyWL6uR0QX8woDgDw&usg=AFQjCNGQGvt8zHAS8QC4ogh8IS4850XgJA&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k) or [Xapian](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=xapian%20search&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://xapian.org/&ei=s1UyUa7bCIrN0QWjhYCgDQ&usg=AFQjCNGM5Sa2hXktsiZR_x-rXyQ8kbZytA&bvm=bv.43148975,d.d2k)

Comment: One more thing. I've read you can INDEX only the first few chars from a VARCHAR. If I index the first 5 chars of the field, would it only help with the `LIKE 'str%'` queries or also with the `field IN ('str..')` ones?